# Toggling between Fn and F keys per app

Tags: macos, keyboard, applications, shortcut, vmware

Is there a way to toggle between Fn (multimedia keys, brightness, etc) and F keys (F1, F2, ...) per app? I used to use an app that could perform this but now I just can't remember it's name.

As a developer I use a vmware fusion virtual machine to maintain some windows apps, and it would great if I could just enter the VM with the keyboard toggled to F keys, and when I get back to the OSX the keyboard gets toggled back to Fn keys.

Any ideas?